# The domain of the functions f(x)=√log1/2(2x-x^2) is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, domain-theory

Given that $$f(x)=\sqrt{\log(2x-x^2)}$$ then find the domain of $f(x)$

**My solution:**

$\log(2x-x^2)\geq0$

$\implies 2x-x^2\geq1 \implies x\leq1$

Also,

$2x-x^2\gt0$

$\implies x\gt0$ ,$\ x\lt2$

On finding the intersection,

$x\in(0,1]$

I can't figure out where I went wrong here, The given solution is ${\{1\}}$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:

$$2x - x^2 \ge 1 \iff x^2-2x+1 \le 0 \iff (x-1)^2\le 0 \iff x=1$$

Besides, the second inequality $2x - x^2 > 0$ is implied by the first.